# br tag is not visible

Tags: html, css

I want to hide all content on page except one div.

It works, but inside that div `<br>` tag is not visible.

```
<div id='min320'>min 320px<br>screen width required</div>
```

css

```
html body * {
 display:none;
}

#min320{
    display:block;
    background-color:#b30000;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffffff;
    padding:5px 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q59Jc/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add display also to `<br>`

Just add:

```
#min320 br{
    display:block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q59Jc/3/)

Comment: Thanks laaposto, but `br` is child of `min320`, it should be visible if `min320` is visible, shoudn't?

Comment: @bonaca No. You can have a parent visible but his child not. It depends on how you declare it in your CSS

Comment: You specifically asks for #min320 to be visible. If you want all childs to be visible aswell, you should use #min320, #min320 * { display:block; }

Answer (score 2):

Your hiding everything with display none on the "*" element.
This means you have to display block on the 
 element aswell.

```
#min320 br {
    display:block;
}
```

If you want all of #min320 child elements to be visible. You could do this

```
#min320, #min320 * { 
display:block; 
}
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Well sure, you display everything that is inside the body as none, here:

```
html body * {
    display:none;
}
```

Display your `<br>` how it should be displayed:

```
html body br{display:inline}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/q59Jc/4/)

Answer (score 2):

The selector `html body *` matches all descendants of `body`, including the `br` element. To fix this, use a [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors) instead:

```
body > * {
    display:none;
}
```

(The `html` part is redundant.)

This matches all children of `body`. Then you just override this for the single element, as you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

This was causing the problem:

```
html body * {
  display:none;
}
```

Change it to:

```
html body * {
  display:block;
}
```

It will work. Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KLHdz/1/